# Can I record playback with audacity without Pulseaudio?

Tags: sound, alsa, audacity, audio-recording

I'm trying to record output (that which I can hear) with Audacity, but no sound is being recorded.

I have found some instructions on how to record with Pulseaudio, but I have only Alsa. I can't see any option in alsamixer or audacity.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends highly on your sound card. To do so without some kind of software intervention would require a "full duplex" sound card.

Basically look in ALSA Mixer (`alsamixer`) and hit [Tab] till your on the "capture" page. Then if you have the option to select either "Monitor" or "PCM" choose that and you should be capturing your output.

Many, many computers do not have full duplex cards, in addition the channels may be named something else.

There are some options, if you do not have a full duplex card. [This site](http://www.swview.org/blog/how-redirect-alsa-output-file) should get you started, but recording the playing sound, generally requires a *better then average* sound card.